# Specify output directory for R package generation

Tags: r, package

I am trying to automize the procedure of package generation but seem to be unable to tell R where to save the newly generated package.

Here a more detailed explanation of my problem:

First I write a function (or multiple functions) and save it as a separate file in a source directory ("C:/Users/Raphael/Documents/Stats/R/Package_Forge/testpack_SourceFiles") that will be used to generate the package. For illustration purposes, I am using the following test function (file: testpack_test.R). As you can see I am using Hadley Wickham’s roxygen package.

```
#' @rdname f.test
#' @title Test function
#' @description This function squares a given number.
#' @param x Number
#' @return The function returns a number
#' @export
#' 
f.test=function(x){
  x=x^2
  return(x)
}
```

Then I use the following script to generate the package, which in this example contains only one function (f.test):

```
#######################
#*** Load packages ***#
#######################
# Set library path
.libPaths("C:/Users/Raphael/Documents/Stats/R/Package_Use")

#install.packages("roxygen2")
library(digest)
library(roxygen2)

###################
#*** Set paths ***#
###################
# Define Path
pkForge="C:/Users/Raphael/Documents/Stats/R/Package_Forge"
pkUse="C:/Users/Raphael/Documents/Stats/R/Package_Use"
newPk=file.path(pkForge,"testpack")
newPkS=file.path(pkForge,"testpack_SourceFiles")
newPkR=file.path(newPk,"R") #"R" folder that will contain functions
newPkD=file.path(newPk,"DESCRIPTION") #Description file

############################################
#*** Generate directories and add files ***#
############################################
# Generate main directory of new package
if(file.exists(newPk)){
  cat("\nExisting directory deleted!")
  unlink(newPk,recursive=T) #deletes old directory
  cat("\nNew directory generated!\n",newPk)
  dir.create(newPk)
}else{
  cat("\nNew directory generated!\n",newPk)
  dir.create(newPk)
}

# Generate "R" sub directory of new package
dir.create(newPkR)

# Add all scripts in the source directory to "R" sub directory
# Note: roxygen code should be used for function annotation
allScripts=list.files(newPkS,"^testpack_.*?\\.R$", full.names=T, ignore.case=T) #uses regex to only select certain files; returns the entire path 
file.copy(allScripts, newPkR)

# Generate a new description file in the package main directory
fileConn=file(newPkD,open="w")
writeLines(c("Package: testpack",
             "Type: Package",
             "Title: Test package",
             "Version: 1.0",
             "Date: 2013-08-04",
             "Author: XYZ",
             "Maintainer: XYZ <xyz@gmail.com>",
             "Description: This package contains one test function",
             "License:GPL-2"),fileConn)
close(fileConn)
# file.show(newPkD) #shows the content of new file

############################
#*** Roxygenize package ***#
############################
# list.files(MyPackages) 
roxygenize(newPk)

#######################
#*** Build package ***#
#######################
cmd=paste("R CMD build ", shQuote(newPk)," --no-manual --no-resave-data", sep="")
system(cmd) #using a system call to build the package
```

This last system call builds the source package correctly. However, the problem is that for some reasons the “tarball” (testpack_1.0.tar.gz) is always saved to C:/Users/Raphael/Documents and I seem to be unable to specify an output directory. I would like to have the tarball saved directly to the pkUse directory ("C:/Users/Raphael/Documents/Stats/R/Package_Use"), which is the folder that I use for all my installed libraries. I tried to add the pkUse directory at various places in the “cmd” string ("R CMD build \"C:/Users/Raphael/Documents/Stats/R/Package_Forge/testpack\" --no-manual --no-resave-data") but it always gives an error. Does anyone have an idea of how to specify the output directory in the above system call? I know that the devtools package is able to do this but would like to be able to use the system call. Thanks so much for any suggestions!

Best,
Raphael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tarball is being saved to the working directory, so you could `setwd()` before your system call, then set it back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `sink`?

`sink(x)` will write the output to the directory and file format that you need.